# Migrating site from MariaDB to MS SQL 2012

Tags: database, migrations

I'm trying to migrate the site from a linux+mariadb platform to IIS+MS SQL platform. Could someone please tell me what is the best way to do this?

What I've done so far:

- Installed a vanilla Drupal site on IIS server to ensure everything works.
- Tried migrating the database with SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA): https://stackoverflow.com/a/13898291/3199478

It's a Drupal 8 site so the [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) and [Migrate D2D](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) modules are useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to migrate the DBs in the following manner:

1. Install MySQL on the target machine.
2. Load the MariaDB in MySQL. Since it is supposed to be a drop-in replacement, this should go smoothly.
3. Create an empty database in MS SQL 2012.
4. Use the SSMA to migrate the DB into MS SQL 2012.

   - The migration will throw a whole bunch of warnings at you. Most of these have to do with truncation due to data-type incompatibility. Don't worry about these. Refer to the schema for the DB that Drupal created when it was installed in MS SQL for reference. For the most part, the data-types would be over compensated, e.g. `int` becomes `bigint`, etc. So you don't really need to do anything, but check anyways.
5. Once the DB has been migrated, change the credentials in `settings.php` to use the new database.
6. Clear caches on the newly migrated site and ensure everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend giving this tool a try. I have used it in the past (to do MSSQL -> MySQL) to setup a datasource for a legacy migration. In your case, you don't need a migration, you just need the db to be in MSSQL format. This is a great litmus test that might save you hours and hours of time.

https://dbconvert.com/mysql/mssql/

It's reasonably priced and worth a shot. If it works fine, you'll move right along.

Comment: Thanks for the link! The price is still too much for me, since I am doing this work pro bono.

Comment: Having been down this road, I highly suggest trying the demo to see if it solves the problem. If it does, $149 (?) is a drop in the bucket vs all the hours you'd spend otherwise, even if it is for free.

Answer (score 0):

If this module ever gets updated to a Drupal 8 version, it could be an option:
https://www.drupal.org/project/dbtng_migrator

It's actually a fairly small module. What the module attempts to do is use the installed modules schema definitions in D7, apply the Schema(s) to the destination DB type and then just grab and insert all the rows from the existing drupal db into the newly created database tables.

The issue queue notes there are some issues with likely dbms vendor specific issues.

**EDIT**

While the above Drupal tool exists to migrate a database from 1 dbms platform to another, it currently relies on Drupal7. Similar tools exist in other languages as well. A relatively popular tool which should handle most-nearly any database popular commercial database can be found here:

- https://github.com/seanharr11/etlalchemy
- http://thelaziestprogrammer.com/sharrington/databases/migrating-between-databases-with-etlalchemy

Comment: Thanks! But as it not available for D8, I cannot use it, nor can I wait long enough for them to migrate.

Comment: @codehitman please see my edit. please learn to Google better, because quite simply all I did was spend some time googling around for similar tools, as what you're doing I've had to do myself before. I've not used the Python tool myself but it has hundreds of commits and should work for many dbms vendors.

Comment: Thanks! I will remember this for the future, and for other non-Drupal related migrations.